# How to create a benchmark with the same and unchanged input?

Tags: php, c++, benchmarking, perf, hhvm

I want the input to be fixed and the number of instructions to not change when I run a benchmark.
How to create a benchmark with the same and unchanged input?
My benchmark is oss-performance ([oss-performance github](https://github.com/facebookarchive/oss-performance)).
I want the following two to have the same output in terms of instruction count.

```
$ perf stat -e L1-icache-load-misses,instruc
tions hhvm perf.php --wordpress --hhvm=/usr/local/bin/hhvm  -c General -r 0

      110647492437      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
     2676929150620      instructions                                                

     316.817844079 seconds time elapsed
```

```
perf stat -e L1-icache-load-misses,instruc
tions hhvm perf.php --wordpress --hhvm=/usr/local/bin/hhvm  -c General -r 0

    110728668966      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
     2677096040536      instructions                                                

     303.617243520 seconds time elapsed
```

While now, as you can see, the output is not the same?
Please help me, I need these outputs to be the same every time so that I can get a trace.

But I don't know what to do.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please comment even if you can. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the program has some timing-dependent paths of execution, for example retries in `clock_gettime` if the kernel timestamp was in mid-update (if it uses a SeqLock).  I don't think clock_gettime retries could account for everything, but if there's any multithreading within `hhvm`, it probably uses some locks.  And those locks probably have spin-retry loops if they find the lock was not available, before falling back to a `futex` system call.

Perhaps it could help to `taskset -c 1 perf stat ...` or something to pin everything to one core, so only one thread could ever execute at once.  But that doesn't stop an unlucky context switch from putting a thread to sleep while it holds a lock, leading to others failing to get a lock.

This might make it more granular, like if everything happens to schedule perfectly, you get the minimum, and if not you get some fixed number of extra instructions per time a thread went to sleep while holding a lock.